# Return multiple columns with sql: ERROR query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Hei,

Been looking for a fix to this, but no luck. I want to return multiple columns.

Error code:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function name(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name(vn CHARACTER VARYING)
    RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT
    (SELECT row FROM TableName AS tn WHERE tn.viitenumber = vn) AS vn1,
    (SELECT row FROM TableName AS tn WHERE tn.viitenumber = vn) AS vn2;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I was able to return one column with

```
RETURN(SELECT TableName FROM lepingu_lisad AS ll WHERE ll.viitenumber = vn) AS vn1;
```

but how do i return both colums

Comment: You have a scalar function - that can only return a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name
(vn CHARACTER VARYING,
 OUT vn1 CHARACTER VARYING,
 OUT vn2 CHARACTER VARYING) AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT
    SELECT row into vn1 FROM TableName AS tn WHERE tn.viitenumber = vn;
    SELECT row into vn2 FROM TableName AS tn WHERE tn.viitenumber = vn;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Usage would be:

```
select (name_results).vn1, (name_results).vn2 from name(_vn) name_results;
```